# Weird side effect when rounding BigDecimals

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to use only the 8 digits after the floating point and round the rest to the ceiling. When the input is 0.0, after the rounding operation, I have `0E-8` instead of `0.00000000`

```
val test = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0)
println(test.setScale(8, RoundingMode.CEILING))
```

When I change the value with 2.0 the result is fine as I expected `2.00000000`

I am new at Kotlin. I don't understand the reason.

Comment: You might want to look into [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html) for your use case.

Comment: Not related to your specific problem, but using `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` is asking for trouble.

Comment: isn't `0E-8` exactly `0.00000000`?

Comment: Mark means `BigDecimal.valueOf("2.000")` even provides a precision, whereas `BigDecimal.valueOf(2.1)` uses the floating point 2.1, an actual approximation, maybe something like 2.0999934.

Comment: I find the sweeping rule applies here - never use `toString` to format something for the end user.

Answer (score 6):

Whether `toString` returns the number in exponential notation or not is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString()):

> first, the absolute value of the unscaled value of the `BigDecimal` is
> converted to a string in base ten using the characters '0' through '9'
> with no leading zeros (except if its value is zero, in which case a
> single '0' character is used).
>
> Next, an adjusted exponent is calculated; this is the negated scale,
> plus the number of characters in the converted unscaled value, less
> one. That is, `-scale+(ulength-1)`, where `ulength` is the length of
> the absolute value of the unscaled value in decimal digits (its
> precision).
>
> If the scale is greater than or equal to zero and the adjusted
> exponent is greater than or equal to -6, the number will be converted
> to a character form without using exponential notation. [...]
>
> Otherwise (that is, if the scale is negative, or the adjusted exponent
> is less than -6), the number will be converted to a character form
> using exponential notation. [...]

In the 0 case, the unscaled value is "0", according to the documentation. This has the length of 1. Therefore, the adjusted exponent is -8 + (1 - 1) = -8. This is less than -6, so it is displayed in exponential notation.

When the number is 2, the unscaled value is "200000000", and the scale of 8 scales it down it "2.00000000". The unscaled value has a length of 9. Therefore, the adjusted exponent is -8 + (9 - 1) = 0. This is greater than -6, and the scale of 8 is greater than 0, so 2.00000000 is not displayed in  exponential notation.

Note that you can always get a string that is not in exponential notation by calling [`toPlainString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()).